# SQL query for dynamic table column selection from checkbox in codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, dynamic, checkbox

I am trying to retrieve the columns from the database based on checkbox selection in codeigniter. But I have no idea how to do it?

For example there's a columns in a database table Member:

```
|  ID   | Name   | Gender   | Status  |
---------------------------------------
|  1    | Anne   |  F       | Member  |
|  2    | Brown  |  M       | Member  |
|  3    | Carl   |  M       | Member  |
```

---

Then there's checkboxes in the data.php view to select which column to display

```
<?php echo form_open(data/getData);?>
<label class="col-md-4" for="parameter">Parameter</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="checkbox" id="parameter" value="name"> Name <br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="parameter" value="gender"> Gender <br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="parameter" value="status"> status <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-info" value="Process" />
<?php echo form_close();?>

<div class="well">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr class="info">
         <th>ID</th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <?php foreach($query as $d): ?>
        <tr> 
         <td><?php echo $d['ID'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $d[''];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $d[''];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $d[''];?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach ?>
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

How to dynamically make the column name retrieved from the checkbox?

Data_model.php:

```
function getData(){
  //I don't know how to get the dynamic column select from the view to the select query

  $this->db->select(?);
  $this->db->from('member');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

Anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this simple approach , make a POST/GET with a name attribute `param[]` an array

```
<input type="checkbox" id="parameter" name="param[]" value="name"> Name <br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="parameter" name="param[]" value="gender"> Gender <br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="parameter" name="param[]" value="status"> status <br>
```

in PHP (assuming post value)

```
$param = $this->input->post('param');

//if no param get all columns
if(empty($param)){
 $param = '*';
}else{

  //if array value is more than 1 use implode else just take the 1st array
  $param = (count($param) > 1 ) ? implode(',', $param) : $param[0]; //make a single string and concatenate them with , 
}
example output: name,status
```

then use $param in your model like this `$this->db->select("$param");`

Comment: id should be unique in a page [though it's not an issue here]. Other than this I think it should work.

Comment: Got a warning. Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed.

Comment: @JessMoi, updated the snippet for data handling. I assume you got the error because there's 1 element present in the array.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña , Yep it works. Just delete the quotation marks $this->db->select($param) .Thanks so much. Get a new problem though. How to dynamically make the column name in the view page based on the selected column from the checkbox?